# How to get the sum of a pivot table column in Laravel Filament?

Tags: mysql, laravel-filament

My Workshop model has this relationship to User model. user_workshop being the pivot table.

```
public function users(): BelongsToMany
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_workshop')
    ->withPivot('num_attending', 'price', 'paid_at');
  }
```

I would like to get number of places (spots) sold. A user can buy 1 or 2 spots. In Filament table I'm trying to

```
->sum('users', 'user_workshop.num_attending')
```

This produces this query

```
select `workshops`.*, (select sum(`user_workshop`.`num_attending`) from `users` inner join `user_workshop` on `users`.`id` = `user_workshop`.`user_id` where `workshops`.`id` = `user_workshop`.`workshop_id` and `users`.`deleted_at` is null) as `users_sum_users_workshopnum_attending` from `workshops` where `workshops`.`event_id` = 3 and `workshops`.`event_id` is not null limit 10 offset 0
```

And I get the **correct** result under `users_sum_users_workshopnum_attending` when I'm querying the database directly.

In Filament I'm trying this (but the column is blank)

```
TextColumn::make('users_sum_users_workshopnum_attending')
          ->sum('users', 'user_workshop.num_attending')
          ->label('Sold'),
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To display a count of relationships in the table, you can use `->counts()`

```php
TextColumn::make('users_sum_num_attending')->sum('users', 'num_attending'),
```

for more details, you can check the [Filament Column Relationship](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/tables/columns/relationships#aggregating-relationships)

Comment: It's very useful. You save my time bro. 